# Check if coordinate is connected to the starting coordinate

Tags: javascript, jquery

#### Aim of my code.

1. Left-click on the blue box, will activate them.
2. Box can only be activated if, it is connected to *Starting Point* (The red box).
3. Right-click on the activated box will deactivate that box, and every other boxes that are connected to the *Starting Point* through it.

#### Current Status & Problem

I have finish writing code for activating the box. Now I'm stuck with the deactivation part. As for now, right click will only deactivate the target box alone.

My goal is to make sure all the box that have lost connection to the *Starting Point* (as a result of this box deactivation) will be deactivated as well.

#### Fiddle & Recreate Problem

http://jsfiddle.net/8wj48bv5/3/

1. In that fiddle, activate all 'I' and 'O' boxes.
2. When we deactivate the 'I' boxes, the 'O' boxes will lost the route to the *Starting Point*, and they should be deactivated as well.

Part that needs to be done:

```
    function deactivateBox(a, b) {
    var r, c; // Row, Column

    if (typeof a == "string") {
        var coor = a.split(',');
        r = parseInt(coor[0]);
        c = parseInt(coor[1]);
    } else {
        r = parseInt(a);
        c = parseInt(b);
    }
    var cur = $('.talent-list a[data-col-coor="' + r + ',' + c + '"]');

    if (!cur.hasClass('active')) {
        console.log('Not yet actived.');
        return;
    } else {
        cur.removeClass('active');
        skill_point++;

        // Check and deactivate disconnected box.
        removeDisconnected(r, c);

        console.info('Deactivate : ', r, ',', c, skill_point, ' Talent Point left.')
    }
        }

    function removeDisconnected(r, c) {
    // Check and deactivate disconnected box.
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: now you found the fun part and will need some recursion

Comment: Yes, I have try making it reclusive. But, when user make a new alternative route from the starting point, every box that were using old route are still being deactivated.

http://jsfiddle.net/8wj48bv5/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution somewhere else. For those who are interested, here's the fiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/jd1htegL/1/

```
    fiddle
```